# Import Resolve Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar

for a little project of mine I want to read a JSON from a Webservice. For this I want to use GSON. My Problem is that I cannot import the dependencies into my eclipse-project. I put the jars into my classpath and they really are in the .classpath-File. The strange thing is, that the eclipse autocomplete suggests me to import the GSON-FIles, but in the import section the import "com.google" cannot be resolved.

It looks like this:
[Picture of file in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUmI5.png)

It also does not only happen with GSON, it seems like nothing from a imported .jar can be resolved.

I hope one of you guys knows a solution to my problem.

**EDIT**

I figured it out myself, didn't consider the module-info java10 creates. By adding `requires gson` it worked fine.

Comment: Please add the error message and the content of the `.classpath` file to your question.

Answer (score 1):

For me this procedure work well:

1. create a folder lib into your src folder
2. copy the jar folder into it
3. open file properties -> java build path
4. select module path option
5. select the jar file copied in lib folder
6. click on ok button
7. click on apply and close to complete

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your **project> Properties> java build path> Libraries** are you able to see the required jar file if not please add via add external jars.
Do Project > clean

Comment: The jar file is already in my project folder and added to the BuildPath. I already cleaned it multiple times and still nothing happened.

Comment: what kind of project it is? maven or gradle or simple java project

Comment: It's a simple Java project, but I already figured it out. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove existing jar entry from build path.
2. Put the jar gson-2.2.4.jar in some folder, for example E:\external-jar\gson-2.2.4.jar
3. Right click on the project and go to build path then click on "Add External Archives..".
4. Select the gson-2.2.4.jar and click open.
5. The gson-2.2.4.jar will now appear in the referenced libraries.

Hope this help! Let me know if you still face issues.