# Import Resolve Error in Eclipse with GSON

Tags: java, eclipse, gson

I am trying to use GSON with eclispe to parse JSON files. I downloaded gson-2.9.1.jar and added it to Project> Properties> Java Build Path> Libraries classpath but when I try
`import com.google.gson.Gson;`
I get an error saying "the type com.google.gson.GSON is not accessible". This is the exact same problem described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684007/import-resolve-error-in-eclipse). The author has an edit saying they fixed it:

> "By adding *requires gson* it worked fine."

But I don't know what that means and none of the responses on that post actually say how to solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: That would go in the `module-info.java`

Comment: When you have a `module-info.java` file, the `gson-2.9.1.jar` has to be added to the modulepath, not to the classpath and in `module-info.java` a `requires ...;` is needed. Do you have a `module-info.java` file and does deleting it fix your issue?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Added to modulepath, edited module-info.java with the requires and the import works